# Use my smartphone as hotspot only

Tags: wifi-hotspot, internet

I often turn on the hotspot on my phone to use the data connection on my laptop throgh wifi.

Anyway, the connection is often unstable. For example, when a Whatsapp message arrives, then the connection slows down, or it falls down.

I know that I can block the access to internet for every single application.
I was wondering if there is a easy way to block **all** internet activities of my phone while I use it as hotspot.

Thanks in advance!

Note that I don't have a rooted phone.

Comment: With root you need to add a simple `iptables` rule.

Comment: @IrfanLatif thanks, but I don't have arooted phone. Is there a more "plain" way to this?

Comment: VPN based firewall can be used to block connections but it's not as robust as `iptables` or `ip route`/`ip rule` is. You can check existing VPN firewall apps if they provide an option to block all apps in single step.

Comment: Press the whatsapp icon until the circled i shows up, and tap that. click Notifications and turn them off? Don't forget to turn them back on. Alternatively (again long press to get the circled i) and tap Force stop. Then when done open whatsapp back up to restart the process.

Comment: @JimClark this is a very basic solution, and I'm aware of it. Anyway, whatsapp was just one example of app that connects to internet... I'd like a plain solution, i.e. something that can be performed using basic apps found on the store.

Comment: @IrfanLatif ok for the VPN, but then, how do I do this?